# Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\projectname.exe'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, debugging, x86

I have developed a windows application using C# VS 2010. It was working perfectly fine untill I added another project for making a setup.exe to be distributed. But now when I try to run my project it gives error **"Could not find file 'obj\x86\Debug\projectname.exe'."** and asks if I would like to continue and run the last successful build? If I choose yes it runs a previouse version of application and don't show latest functions and interface changes which I made.  Now setup project has been removed and there is single project in solution but still getting same error. I checked debug folder and there is no file named as projectname.exe.
NOTE : Projectname is name of my project

Comment: This usually means you had another compilation error which stopped `projectname.exe` from being created. Is this the only error you get?

Comment: yes you are right and its only error I get. I checked debug folder and there is no projectname.exe file.

Comment: And you don't get any other errors/messages that indicate why that file isn't being created?

Comment: to distribute this application on some other machines I added another project to solution and named it setup. it was successfully published and installed on other machines meanwhile I needed to add some functionality to application but now I am facing this problem when I try to run it.

Comment: I got that. Do your projects compile without the setup project?

Comment: this is the only error I am facing. there is no other error or warning :(

Comment: yes I removed setup project already but still getting same problem

Comment: We are going to need more details to help you. What projects do you have in this solution and how do they depend on each other? What is `projectname.exe`? A setup file? Application exe?

Comment: Projectname is name of my project I am developing. It is set as startup project. other project which was added and named as setupproject is of "setup and deployment" type. Now I have removed setupproject from solution and there is only one project in solution now.

Comment: Update these details in the question itself and add more details. How is the build doing after these changes and etc...

Answer (score 2):

Well Avast antivirus was a problem. I don't know how but I turned off avast and build my application and it worked just fine. ... not a big proble .. sighhhhhhhh